# Directory instead of packages ,Is it same?

Tags: flutter

I am a new Flutter developer I use Android in my practice when I was using an old version I was able to create dart packages from the menu add package Now I just found a directory instead of packages Is it the same? If not, how can I find a way from the menu to create a dart package in Flutter?

Directory instead of packages ,Is it same?

Comment: Just use `dart create` from the command line.